# Android EditText tinting issues on API 22

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm having a weird issue on Android 5.1 (API level 22) where if i use a `controlColorNormal` and `controlColorActivated` that reference a colour resource that is overridden in the `land` folder, when the device is rotated, the `EditText` background (the underline) is not tinted with the correct `land` colour, but with the base variant (or the other way around, if the app is started in `land` orientation).

This works fine on Android 5.0.x and lower, it's just misbehaving on 5.1.

Here is a PoC project with a more in-depth description and some screenshots: https://github.com/rock3r/EditTextTinting

Has anyone seen this happening, and possibly found a workaround for it?